# VS WPF Program keeps crashing when checking if statement

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, crash

i just finished making an WPF program by Visual Studio 2012 about a simple Students Grading System.

all goes fine and it shows no error or invalid statements (red lines)
and there is a submit button, but whenever i press it a second time, the program crashes.
i checked my code several times and i can't find a solution. so it might be bother :S
the program works such as this:
the user have to enter a number of students to put grades. --> press OK, list of fields appear, when the user done inputting grades --> press submit. the values are all entered to 2 arrays, one for names and the other for grades which will be converted to letters.
the fields will be cleared for the second students, and so on until the number of students reached. the program should give a messagebox with containing the names and their Letter-grades.

```
using System.IO;

namespace Grading_System_Project_3
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public static int nbofstudents;
        public double m1, m2, p1, p2, f;
        public int i = 0;
        public int l;
        public double avg;
        public string name;
        public char fg;
        public char[] gr;
        public string[] names;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) <= 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Enter a valid students number");
            }
            else
            {

                nbofstudents = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);


                StreamWriter SW = File.CreateText(@"C:\grades.txt");
                SW.Close();


                textBox2.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                textBox3.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                textBox4.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                textBox5.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                textBox6.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                textBox7.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                label2.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                label3.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                label4.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                label5.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                label6.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                label7.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            }
        }

        private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            StreamWriter sw2 = new StreamWriter(@"C:\grades.txt");
                if (i < nbofstudents)
                {
                    name = textBox2.Text;
                    m1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);
                    m2 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text);
                    p1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox5.Text);
                    p2 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox6.Text);
                    f = Convert.ToInt32(textBox7.Text);

                    avg = (m1 + m2 + p1 + p2 + f) / 5;

                    if (avg >= 0 && avg <= 59)
                    {
                        fg = 'F';
                    }
                    else if (avg >= 60 && avg <= 69)
                    {
                        fg = 'D';
                    }
                    else if (avg >= 70 && avg <= 79)
                    {
                        fg = 'C';
                    }
                    else if (avg >= 80 && avg <= 89)
                    {
                        fg = 'B';
                    }
                    else if (avg >= 90 && avg <= 100)
                    {
                        fg = 'A';
                    }

                    string temp = Convert.ToString(fg);

                    try
                    {
                        sw2.WriteLine(name + "\t" + temp);
                        sw2.WriteLine();
                        sw2.Close();
                    }
                    catch (IOException ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }

                    i++;
                    textBox2.Clear();
                    textBox3.Clear();
                    textBox4.Clear();
                    textBox5.Clear();
                    textBox6.Clear();
                    textBox7.Clear();
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        StreamReader rf = new StreamReader(@"C:\grades.txt");
                        string s = "";
                        while ((s = rf.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(rf.ReadLine());
                        }
                        rf.Close();
                    }
                    catch (IOException ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }

                }



            }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post exception information about the crash? On the face of it, I can see where you check `if (i < nbofstudents)`, then increment it `i++`, then start accessing elements of the `gr` and `names` array. This can be a problem because say if `nbofstudents` is 10, then when `i` is 9, it will still pass the `if` condition, increment itself to `10`, but at this point you can't access `nbofstudents[10]` (highest you can access is 9). You're also skipping entering the `0` element. You should move the `i++` increment to _after_ you assign `gr[i] = fg` and `names[i] = name`.

Comment: Just as a side note, what you are trying to do (data entry) is really better suited for MVVM and data-binding, and you could save yourself a lot of work in the long run if you used this technique. [Here's](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Data-Driven-Applications-with-MVVM-Part-I.-The-Basics.aspx) a good tutorial to start off with, it's Silverlight based but the same principles apply to WPF.

Comment: Thanks For Replying. i can't get the exception information, but from debug window, i get "System.FormatException" and at "m1 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text);" it says cannot convert string to Date format. //something like that

Comment: The documentation of `Convert.ToDouble` (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh1hkw6k.aspx) tells what exceptions it can throw. None of the 5 calls of `Convert.ToDouble` have any checks that the text provided will be a valid number and none have any `catch` code to handle invalid numbers.

Comment: Edited my post, now i'm used streamwriter to save values into file and then retrieve it. it still crashes when number of students are reached.

Comment: Like @AdrianHHH said, add `try` and `catch` blocks to your calls to `Convert.ToInt32`... a user could add letters into the `TextBoxes`. Another problem is that you are calling `rf.ReadLine()` twice! Replace `MessageBox.Show(rf.ReadLine());` with `MessageBox.Show(s);`

Comment: Thank You all for your time and answers. much appreciated. i just did a full check of my code while putting up your suggestions in mind. i did a several changes to the program and now it's better than the given one and works flawlessly. thank you again.